# ADFS server won't authenticate to Azure AD

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, adfs

I have an Azure AD with a domain `myDomain.onmicrosoft.com`

I have some users from an on-prem AD that are synced to this AAD. I am using the AAD for authentication in a web app but I cannot get my users that are from the on-prem AD to authenticate to the app.

It is setup now to utilize an ADFS server we have on-prem - so when the user clicks login he is directed to our ADFS (`https://sts1.<onPremDomain.com>/adfs/etc....`) but when the user tries to login the screen just flashes and goes nowhere. It just blanks out the password.

I notice if I try a wrong password, it will tell me it is wrong, so it's not like the ADFS login screen isn't doing anything. It just doesn't seem to be passing along my credentials or something to the AAD once I log in.

What do I need to do to get this working?  I have access to everything including the Azure portal for the ADD and the ADFS server.

Comment: You have a federated domain? - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/02/06/convert-a-managed-domain-in-azure-ad-to-a-federated-domain-using-adfs-for-on-premises-authentication-step-by-step/

Comment: I'd recommend getting a Fiddler trace of the auth flow to see what's going on. Alternatively, you should also try out these suggestions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3079872/troubleshoot-ad-fs-issues-in-azure-active-directory-and-office-365